# Deviance n.eff in R becoming 1 at high sample n

Tags: r, jags, bugs

I've been doing some basic bayesian t-tests in OpenBUGS, and later JAGS (via a friendly biometrician), and in both cases I ran into a bizarre property of the R-2- packages on the output. Specifically, my deviance in an analysis has collapsed to a single value, with n.eff = 1. Puzzled, I went back to my model and checked it out - everything seemed fine. Just to be sure, I went back to some code from Marc Kery's book

> cat("
>       model {
>
> ```
> # Priors
> mu1 ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
> mu2 ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
> tau1 <- 1 / ( sigma1 * sigma1)
> sigma1 ~ dunif(0, 1000)       # Note: Large var. = Small precision
> tau2 <- 1 / ( sigma2 * sigma2)
> sigma2 ~ dunif(0, 1000)
>
> # Likelihood
> for (i in 1:n1) {
> y1[i] ~ dnorm(mu1, tau1) 
> }
>
> for (i in 1:n2) {
> y2[i] ~ dnorm(mu2, tau2) 
> }
>
> # Derived quantities
> delta <- mu2 - mu1
> }
> ",fill=TRUE) sink()
> ```

(etc) and it ran well. However, when I tried to jigger the sample size of the underlaying simulated data

```
n1 <- 6400
n2 <- 6400
mu1 <- 105
mu2 <- 77.5
sigma1 <- 3
sigma2 <- 2.5
{...}
y1 <- rnorm(n1, mu1, sigma1)
y2 <- rnorm(n2, mu2, sigma2)
```

and bound it up and ran it in Marc's example code.
In the end, I see the same issue in the output,

```
Inference for Bugs model at "h.ttest.txt", 
Current: 3 chains, each with 2000 iterations (first 500 discarded)
Cumulative: n.sims = 4500 iterations saved
              mean    sd      2.5%       25%       50%       75%     97.5%  Rhat n.eff
mu1        105.070 0.357   104.400   104.800   105.100   105.300   105.800 1.002  1200
mu2         77.468 0.032    77.410    77.450    77.470    77.490    77.530 1.001  4500
delta      -27.602 0.356   -28.300   -27.830   -27.610   -27.360   -26.895 1.002  1300
sigma1       2.692 0.263     2.237     2.507     2.672     2.853     3.267 1.001  4000
sigma2       2.505 0.022     2.464     2.489     2.505     2.520     2.548 1.001  4500
deviance 30200.918 2.910 30200.000 30200.000 30200.000 30200.000 30210.000 1.000     1
```

If I peel the data n back a bit to ~1000, I eventually get back to an expected looking deviance

```
deviance 489.528 2.945 485.900 487.400 488.900 490.900 496.900 1.004   630
```

When I actually inspect the chains for either, nothing looks amiss, making me think this is an R problem. And the fact that when the biometrician tried it in JAGS and found the same thing, it makes this seem all the more reasonable.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: resurrecting old thread -- did you every figure out what was going on here?